# Git Bash (1.9.0) using Windows Explorer intergration crashes folder explorer

Tags: git, bash, windows-8

Every time i open Git Bash from a folder the folder crashes and cant be used until the Git Bash has been closed. Once the Git Bash is closed the folder starts responding.
I'm using 1.9.0 Git version(latest).
Running Windows 8.
I'll be happy to provide system specs if needed.
I can't upload images because of lack of reputation points, if someone has difficulty understanding the problem here is a detailed explanation of what im doing :

1. Windows key + E -> open folder explorer
2. Right click(select Git Bash from dropdown menu)
3. Starting Git Bash results in this folder being unusable.

This happens everywhere, if i start Git Bash from the desktop, desktop doesn't respond until Git Bash has been closed.

Comment: But... there is no 1.9.2 version of Git for Windows, is there? (https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=1&q=Portable&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount): 1.9.0 only

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm running 1.9.0

Comment: Is this an anti-virus issue? (did you try to de-activate it?)

Comment: I deactivated my anti-virus (NOD32), yet the problem persists.

Comment: Can you try installing msysgit by simply unzipping the portable archive? https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217.7z&can=1&q=Portable, and see if that Git Bash from the portable works better.

Comment: To amend my previous comment, there is a Git for Windows 1.9.2 now (since 13 days ago): https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug is fixed in 1.9.2 (latest version as of now). [Download here](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/).

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This is a reported bug, with a [fix already](https://github.com/msysgit/Git-Cheetah/commit/e7af79862b136efb414ac545f282939e2d290e3e) - not sure when it will be released as a windows install yet.

To fix this problem in git 1.9.0 you must uninstall/reinstall. On reinstalling select the following options.

```
[x] Windows Explorer integration
   (*) Simple context menu (Registry based)
     [x] Git Bash Here
     [x] Git GUI Here
( ) Advanced context menu (git-cheetah plug-in)
```

This way, the bug with the git-cheetah plugin will longer present itself.

Comment: +1. And there is a Git for Windows 1.9.2 now: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/

Comment: Problem is fixed in 1.9.2, just upgraded and used the git-cheetah plugin. Have updated my answer.

Comment: I will reinstall with the git configuration you have suggested and will get back to you asap.

Comment: @user3198079 - may as well upgrade to the latest git.

Comment: Yes, was planning on giving the latest git a chance :)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the support Steven Wong!